# Maven ignores plugin configuration from pom.xml

Tags: maven, cucumber, mojo

While executing a phase everything works as expected, when I try to call a plugin (mojo) directly like

```
mvn net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.5.0:generate
```

maven seems to ignore <configuration></configuration> block of the plugin specified in pom.xml. And if a parameter of the plugin is required, maven obviously fails as it thinks it is not set (did you try to look at your pom.xml, dear maven?). Is this by designed or I misunderstand something?

Comment: Which maven version are you using?

Comment: @khmarbaise 3.5.4 on JDK 8

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have put the `<configuration>` into an `<execution>` block.

If this is the case, move it out of `<executions>`.

Comment: I tried both ways: in and out \<execution\> block - result is the same